# Steel wool photography: how to obtain lots of sparks?

Tags: night, long-exposure, light-painting

what's the secret to get lots of sparks from the steel wool in this type of photography?

My steel wool usually stops sparking after 7-8 seconds. I think this one sparked for a longer time!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using more steel wool?

Comment: The [grade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_wool#Grades) of the wool might matter as well. A finer wool burns more rapidly due to the larger surface area, yielding a denser shower of sparks but also burning out faster.

Answer (score 1):

Not my ideas - culled from web.
Consensus seems to be that smaller grades are best.
eg from photo extremist below "Get Grade 0, 00, 000, or 0000. Don't get anything at or above Grade 1."

Where times are given they are often around 5 seconds.

[**Tutorial**](http://digital-photography-school.com/playing-fire-steel-wool-spinning-landscape/) by NZ photographer.

See also his [**Vast range of 'how to' series of articles'**](http://digital-photography-school.com/author/andrewgibson/) - the few that I have looked at so far are excellent.

Exposure comments and wool grade here [**Raining fire photography**](http://www.mymodernmet.com/profiles/blogs/spinning-wool-photos-steven-schubert)

Excellent tutorial with 7:40 video. Looks good. Specific advice on wool size.
[**Steel wool photography tutorial**](http://photoextremist.com/steel-wool-photography-tutorial)

---

[**Some of these people are sure to give some clues :-)**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=steel+wool+photography&tbm=isch&imgil=-OnU-0Lq-92UJM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcRbDIv-cXW-39JmID-97UMvZtfKrM1laXGobMAi0oQD-8oC8nF3IA%253B640%253B360%253BGuOgEf1DMWB30M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmycameratrip.blogspot.com%25252F2013%25252F09%25252Famazing-photos-steel-wool-photography.html&source=iu&tbs=simg:CAESmwEamAELEKjU2AQaAggCDAsQsIynCBo8CjoIAhIUiBTNCosUiRSvIdAKtRKzE4YUsggaIG64KG8wileoiTISvLZmFcSoCRaWXTY83UpjTI18rGtGDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIErx1HDgwLEJ3twQkaLAoJCgd0ZXh0dXJlCgoKCGZpcmV3b3JrCgoKCHdoaXNrZXJzCgcKBW5pZ2h0DA&usg=__C[Xxod598HPePHUykGj5ihsKrLHo%3D&sa=X&ei=JDp1U-XIBs2D8gX4zYHwBg&ved=0CD0Q9QEwAw&biw=1920&bih=1075) 
and [these](https://www.flickr.com/groups/1777324@N22/)